# How do JavaScript logins hide user sign up information?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question that is bugging me a lot. How do JavaScript logins hide and protect user login information? Their are possible ways of making a login using javascript and html, but the user login information is visible in the coding. Here is a javascript login example:

```
<html>
<head><title>HTML and JAVASCRIPT example</title>
<script>
function what() {
    if (document.ThisForm.Username.value == "Example Username"
            && document.ThisForm.Password.value == "Example Password") {
        document.location.href = "loginsuccess.html"
    }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="ThisForm">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Username or CMSCE email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="70" name="Username" id="hi"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" size="70" name="Password" id="bye"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="what()" value="Login" style="color: white; background-color: black"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear all"></td>
</tr></table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

This coding is a HTML and Javascript login. This login is not safe, because as you can see, the script tag includes the usernames. So how do JavaScript logins keep the login information safe? Please help me!

Comment: Java != JavaScript. These are two different languages and your tags are consistent with the question but your title and question are misleading. I came to this looking for a question about Java then I saw it was about JavaScript. I've edited the question to change references from Java to JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. "Java != JavaScript." Meaning that my coding above is Java? But isn't Java like;

Comment: system.out.println("something");

Comment: You can't do validation like this on client. Username and password is always send to server which does the validation.

Comment: @It'sMe if you knew either language at all you'd know that "!=" means "is not equal to". So ThisClark is saying your original question tags were misleading because this question only contains JavaScript and not any Java. They are entirely different languages and the naming similarity is just an accident of history

Comment: To address your question, the data in your code is protected on the client with data encapsulation and transmitted securely over secure socket layer (https).

Comment: From where did you get this code? Just look at document.ThisForm.Password.value == "Example Password", how would you check for thousands of users using the login? Will you have a thousand checks with all the username and password combinations?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Have a look at the value of document.ThisForm.Password.value.

Comment: @ThisClark, my data in my code is unfortunately not protected on my server. And it is a http://

Comment: Login systems are far from trivial. I wouldn't call this a beginner skill, and I wouldn't teach it in an intro programming class. If you're feeling ambitious about learning this, I suggest start with an existing system like Google Web Login. It will teach you a lot of concepts before you approach building your own: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: How do I learn from the Google Web Login? Do I look at the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not how login works**

**So how does it work?**

The check for whether user entered the correct username and password combination is performed on the server and not on the client.

**How does the information reach the server?**

When you hit submit on the form, a "post" request is sent to the server with your username and password in the body of the request. It is still not secure. Anyone with a network traffic analyzing software like Wireshark can see the request and all its contents. Hence we use SSL, which encrypts the information in the request so it is secure.

**At the Server**, we try to find the username in the database, and if we do find it, we compare the passwords, and if they match, then the user is allowed to login.

Comment: Thanks @Silencer310!

Answer (score -2):

As a person type the username or password they will not dynamically show up in inspect element as `value` parameter. So others will not see the username or password by simply looking through inspect element. So, inspect element is static so-to-speak and will not change in that sense. They will just see how you implement the code but not the password or username itself.

Comment: And do these usernames get stored in a database or where?

Comment: For what it's worth, a javascript query on the password input, such as `$('#password').val()` will return the password. I think it's stored in active memory, definitely not a database.

Comment: They are just waiting for user to click login. By that time I guess it waits in memory but I am not sure

Comment: By "They are waiting" you are referring to the code, right?

Comment: Actually, I meant username and password are waiting

Comment: Waiting for the correct username and password to be entered?

Comment: Ow I misunderstood your implementation. I got your answer right now. Actually way you do the 'login check' is not exactly what it supposed to be. You should be using databases to actually check if user crediantials match with that of database. And you should implement server-side to do check

Comment: Okay! Thanks @Ziya ERKOC

Comment: Then there's another problem. Where does the username and password get hidden